# How to add block html content display in particular div or any particular place by xml file?

Tags: layout, blocks, magento2.3.1

I created **customer_account_login.xml** to add block.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sociallogin" before="-" template="Lucent_SocialLogin::form/sociallogin.phtml" />   
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

So, this **sociallogin.phtml** file load top of the login form.But I need to display that in particular div which have class or id.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have used `before"-"` it will call your phtml before everything in content.

**First method**, you can use something like `before="customer_form_login"` or `after="customer_form_login"` would call your phtml before/after login form.

**Second method**, is through `getChildHtml`.
Call you phtml in any one of the `customer_account_login.xml` block like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sociallogin" before="-" template="Lucent_SocialLogin::form/sociallogin.phtml" />
</block>
```

After that in form/login.phtml, you can call

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('sociallogin');?>
```

anywhere in the file

**Third and easy method**, you can also directly call your `phtml` in any `div` in any `phtml` like this:

```
<div class="Your_Div">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Lucent_SocialLogin::form/sociallogin.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, This is perfect. But here I created custom module so there is not form/login file. I just want to display in particular inner div class.

Comment: The method would be same for all xml file.

Comment: Good to hear that you issue is resolved. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `before="-"` will make the block render on top of all elements inside `<referenceContainer name="content">` .

To create the block in a new HTML div tag, add `htmlTag="div"` attribute and to add a new CSS class to it, add `htmlClass="css-class-name"` .

If you want to render this block in an existing element, find the element name in the `customer_account_login.xml` present in vendor (search for this filename), reference the desired container/block and nest the block inside that.